# XCode lldb CoreData objects debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging, core-data, lldb

Does anyone know how to debug CoreData objects in this case?

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlzfz.png)

In the screenshot in the beginning there is the `print(cardTemplate)` output. Then I tried to print somehow the object from the debugger but no success.